# Schrödinger equation variable substitution

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Here is the equation sets:

$$\frac{-h^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+\frac{h^2}{2m}\left(\frac{\rho(\rho-1)}{\sinh^2x}-\frac{\lambda(\lambda-1)}{\cosh^2x}\right)\psi=E\psi\tag{1}$$

there is a variable substitution here
$\cosh^2x=z$
and in the paper it is defined

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}&=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}=2 \sqrt{z(z-1)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\tag{2} \\
&=2 \sqrt{z(z-1)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}2 \sqrt{z(z-1)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\tag{3}
\end{align}

and it says in the paper by using above equations it can be written

$$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}=4z(z-1)\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial z^2}+2(z-1)\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z}\tag{4}$$

In the second equation I did not understand the expression 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}.$$
How can I get this expansion? Here $\frac{dz}{dx}=2 \sqrt{z(z-1)}$, but in the expression its inverse had been used. Also can you explain me equations 3 and 4, in this respect.

Comment: It looks like $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$ was a typo to me.

Comment: Which paper? Which page?

Comment: The relations in $(2)$ look very iffy to me, the RHS has been commented on but surely it should read $\partial^2 / \partial x^2$ in LHS?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the transformation in eq (2). It should read
$$
\frac{d}{dx}= \frac{dz}{dx}\frac{d}{dz}.
$$

Comment: Yes I agree with you but I wrote same as the source

Comment: If we take $\frac{d}{dx^2}=\frac{dz}{dx}\frac{d}{dz}$, whole of the equations will change. And square of x not only x.

Comment: So
$$\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}=4z(z-1)\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial z^2}+(2z-1)\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z}$$
First term of the right hand side comes from $$\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}$$ and for the whole of the last eq. I guess there is something like derivative of product.